# Can I script an equivalent of "Delete All by Type" in Maya's Hypershade?

Tags: python, maya, mel

Is it possible to write a script in MEL or Python that achieves the same result as selecting: Hypershade Window > Edit > Delete All by Type > Shading Group and Materials.

I tried to solve it for a long time and I have no more ideas; maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

delete all shaders and shading groups:

```
delete `ls -type shadingDependNode`;
delete `ls -type shadingEngine`;
```

However you can not delete `lambert1`, `intialParticleSE` or `initialShadingGroup` which are always present

Python:

```
 import maya.cmds as cmds
 cmds.delete (cmds.ls(type='shadingDependNode'))
 import maya.cmds as cmds
 cmds.delete (cmds.ls(type='shadingEngine'))
```

Note that if you do this your models will have no material assigned, you'll need to re-assign them to `intialShadingGroup` or they will not render properly in your viewpoint